# How to display modules only on search results in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: search, joomla, module

Hello please read the whole question, this isn't just solved by enabling the modules only for the search page:

I have a few modules that are exclusively shown on the search page in Joomla.

I created a hidden menu entry for the search as well in order to tell modules to only show on this page. This works alright, but when I click one of the results and get redirected to the actual result, then the modules, which should only show up on the search page are still shown in the result page.

Any clue how to fix this? Really annoying as I use 3rd party search enhancing modules, and they are showing on the results.

Comment: **Q1** - Which version of Joomla are you using and what is the search enhancing module? **Q2** - What you say is (1) that there is a search result with the link as `domain.com/abc/page.php` clicking on which will open the link's webpage with the modules which not intended there but are only to be displayed on the search page and (2) the same url `domain.com/abc/page.php` if opened directly by pasting in the address bar or from a menu link will not show up those modules? **Q3** - Is the link on the search result this one `domain.com/abc/page.php` or does it have any other string appended to it?

Answer (score 1):

Using standard Joomla, there's no way to target modules to only the search results page and none of the pages that link off the results – but I know you knew that! The hidden menu item is a help, but does not change the menu item of some of the links off that page. It's all to do with the allocation and use of "Itemids" in Joomla.

To be able to target modules more specifically, you need to use a 3rd-party extension. I developed MetaMod (www.metamodpro.com) to cope with exactly this use case. MetaMod is a wrapper module that can then decide just which other module to include in itself (or not). So you assign the MetaMod to the page, then put a snippet of code inside the MetaMod which decides which other module to include.

In this case, I'd use the following in MetaMod:

```
if ($core_genius->check("pagetype = search, searchresults")) return XXX;
// replace XXX with the module id of the module to include
// ONLY on the search page, or the searchresults page, but
// no other type of page.
```

Hope that helps,

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Although MetaMod is great (I've used it myself & Stephen's support is great!) there is another way to do it without using 3rd party extensions.

You could create new module positions in your template above (or below) the module positions you wanted to use and wrap them in an if statement like so:

```
<?php if(!isset(JRequest::getString('searchword'))) : ?> 
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right-search" style="xhtml" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, had misread the question. I amended the answer accordingly.